# Is there a way to find all elements matching a certain style using the DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom, mootools

I want an array of all elements that have fixed position.

This is what I've got so far (mootools code)

```
$$('*').filter(function(aEl){ return aEl.getStyle('position')=='fixed' });
```

Is there a more direct way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

not really, what you posted is the best way of doing it.

but if it's something you do more often, I'd consider abstracting it to a pseudo selector:

```
Selectors.Pseudo.fixed = function(){
    return this.getStyle("position") == "fixed";
};

// can now use it as a part of a normal selector:
console.log(document.getElements("div:fixed"));
```

p.s. this will break in mootools 1.3 as slick uses a different selectors engine.

to make it work in 1.3 do:

```
Slick.definePseudo('fixed',function() {
    return this.getStyle("position") == "fixed";
});
```

and finally, to make it more versatile so you can look up any CSS property as a part of the selector, you can do something like this:

```
Selectors.Pseudo.style = function(key) {
    var styles = key.split("=");
    return styles.length == 2 && this.getStyle(styles[0]) == styles[1];
};
```

and for mootools 1.3:

```
Slick.definePseudo('style', function(key) {
    var styles = key.split("=");
    return styles.length == 2 && this.getStyle(styles[0]) == styles[1];
});
```

how to use it:

```
console.log(document.getElements("div:style(position=fixed)"));
```

http://www.jsfiddle.net/h7JPS/3/

Comment: Thanks for turning me on to [Slick -- an official Mootools project](http://github.com/mootools/slick "Mootool's Slick on GitHub")

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to make a css class

```
.fixed_pos
{
   position: fixed;
}
```

apply this class to elements that you want and then

```
$$(".fixed_pos");
```

That will give you to all the element

Comment: This is true, but in my case I am working with unknown CSS and HTML, so I can't rely on the existence of such a class.  (My code is for a widget that will be injected into a page.)